# Why does the gradient indicate ascent?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I understand why the gradient gives the greatest directional derivative, as a dot product between the direction and the gradient. But I usually see the gradient called as the direction of steepest *ascent*. Why does it specifically indicate ascent, as opposed to for instance steepest descent?

Comment: If the directional derivative in the direction $u$ is positive, then $u$ is a direction of ascent. Moving a short distance in the direction $u$ increases the value of your function.

Comment: The negative of the gradient gives the direction of steepest descent.

Comment: It's really the direction of fastest increase, which is described as "steepest ascent" because we tend to plot functions with the function value on a "vertical" axis, so when you follow the gradient it looks like you're going uphill; also because people tend to use "higher" as a synonym for "greater".

Answer (score 0):

Locally, a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as a Taylor series
$$
f(x+hu) = f(x) +h(\nabla f(x)\cdot u) + O(h^2), 
$$
where $u $ is a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For sufficiently small $h$, if one wishes to maximize $f(x+hu)$, then one must maximize $\nabla f(x)\cdot u$. This maximum is acheived exactly at $u = \nabla f(x) / \lvert\lvert \nabla f(x)\rvert\vert$.

If $\nabla f(x)\neq 0$, this direction indicates ascent as opposed to descent because
$$
\nabla f(x) \cdot \frac{\nabla f(x)} {\lvert\lvert \nabla f(x)\rvert\vert} = \lvert\lvert\nabla f(x)\rvert\vert > 0,
$$
whereas
$$
\nabla f(x) \cdot \left(-\frac{\nabla f(x)} {\lvert\lvert \nabla f(x)\rvert\vert}\right) = -\lvert\lvert\nabla f(x)\rvert\vert < 0
$$